# Angular Filter injection in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a filter and a service in the same module :

```
app.filter( "etatTransfertEnumToStringFilter", [Filters.EtatTransfertEnumToStringFilter] );


app.service( "notificationService",
        ["$rootScope",
            // others dependencies
            "etatTransfertEnumToStringFilter",
            Services.NotificationService] );
```

The filter works well and i can call him from views but when I inject it into my service (like I did above), i get a `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider: etatTransfertEnumToStringFilterProvider <- etatTransfertEnumToStringFilter <- notificationService`.

I asked myself if the filter was well loaded in the injector so I listed all controllers, services and filters loaded with :

```
app._invokeQueue.forEach(function (x) {console.log(x[2][0]);});
```

I can see `etatTransfertEnumToStringFilter` in the list, so i don't get what is going on.

An idea ?

**Edit :** My filter is simple :

```
module Filters {
    "use strict";

    export function EtatTransfertEnumToStringFilter() {
        return ( input: Metier.Model.EtatTransfertEnum ) => {
            return Metier.Model.EtatTransfertEnum[input];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject a filter you have to add the word `Filter` to the name of the filter. So if your filter is named `etatTransfertEnumToStringFilter`, you would inject it using `etatTransfertEnumToStringFilterFilter`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but i forgot that my Filter already contained Filter at the end. Do you know why Angular filters works like that with filters and not services etc ?